# extracting raw gene counts based on the cluster generated by seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, single-cell

I'm new to single cell sequencing analysis. I have made different clusters using seurat. Now I would like to extract the raw gene counts based on the cluster generated by seurat.
i have provided my R code used in the analysis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Seurat)
library(patchwork)
ftp="https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE201nnn/GSE201254/suppl/GSE201254_count_mat_Control-NoCrush.csv.gz"
counts=data.table::fread(ftp)
C_nocrush=counts %>%
select(contains(c("V1","CtCReRGCS")))
rownames(C_nocrush)=C_nocrush$V1
C_nocrush$V1=NULL
CNC=CreateSeuratObject(counts = C_nocrush,project = "He RGC Data", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
CNC[["percent.mt"]] = PercentageFeatureSet(CNC, pattern = "^MT-")
VlnPlot(CNC, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA","percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
plot1 <- FeatureScatter(CNC, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
plot2 <- FeatureScatter(CNC, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
plot1+plot2
CNC = subset(CNC, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < 5)
CNC = NormalizeData(CNC, normalization.method = "LogNormalize", scale.factor = 10000)
CNC = FindVariableFeatures(CNC, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
top10 <- head(VariableFeatures(CNC), 10)
plot1 <- VariableFeaturePlot(CNC)
plot2 <- LabelPoints(plot = plot1, points = top10, repel = TRUE)
plot1+plot2
all.genes <- rownames(CNC)
CNC <- ScaleData(CNC, features = all.genes)
CNC <- RunPCA(CNC, features = VariableFeatures(object = CNC))
VizDimLoadings(CNC, dims = 1:2, reduction = "pca")
DimPlot(CNC, reduction = "pca")
DimHeatmap(CNC, dims = 1:15, cells = 500, balanced = TRUE)
CNC <- JackStraw(CNC, num.replicate = 100)
CNC <- ScoreJackStraw(CNC, dims = 1:20)
JackStrawPlot(CNC, dims = 1:15)
ElbowPlot(CNC)
CNC <- FindNeighbors(CNC, dims = 1:10)
CNC <- FindClusters(CNC, resolution = 0.5)
head(Idents(CNC), 5)
CNC <- RunUMAP(CNC, dims = 1:10)
DimPlot(CNC, reduction = "umap")
saveRDS(CNC, file = "Desktop/Single_cell_RNA/CNC.rds")
cluster2.markers <- FindMarkers(CNC, ident.1 = 2, min.pct = 0.25)
head(cluster2.markers, n = 5)
new.cluster.ids=c("T5/F RGCs", "T5/F RGCs","T-RGCs","Other RGcs and cartpt RGCs","T5/F RGCs","IP-RGCs","Other RGcs and cartpt RGCs","N-RGCs","Alpha-RGCs" )
names(new.cluster.ids)=levels(CNC)
CNC=RenameIdents(CNC,new.cluster.ids)
 DimPlot(CNC,reduction = "umap", label = T, pt.size = 0.5)+NoLegend()
```

Tried using this command to extract the raw counts based on the cluster but is not working for me.

```
meta.data.cluster=unique(x=CNC@meta.data$active.ident)
meta.data.cluster=unique(Idents(CNC))
for(group in meta.data.cluster) {
    group.cells <- WhichCells(object = CNC, idents = group)
    data_to_write_out <- as.data.frame(GetAssayData(CNC,slot = 'counts')[,group.cells])
    write.csv(data_to_write_out, row.names = TRUE, file = "1_cluster_outfile.csv")
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for supplying detailed code. Could you kindly explain the precise question? I assume the code is throwing an error or not working how it was anticipated. Describing this would be great.

Comment: I have updated my script. I want to extract the raw counts of the genes using the selected cluster.

Comment: How do you know that the count extraction code you wrote is not working?